# Desktop application - PHP, HTML, MYSQL

Tags: php, xcode, titanium, desktop

I wrote a web based program using PHP, HTML, CSS and MySQL database. I would now like to convert it into a standalone desktop app for Windows and Apple.

I've done a lot of research and the 'Titanium' SDK has been advised, however even though it includes PHP, it is quite limited. Particularly I can't use `<?php ?>` in a html file to display a PHP variable, PHP `echo` isn't supported, and there seems to be an issue with global variables. While these may seem minimal, it would require considerable reprogramming, some of the functionality which I'm not sure I could re-achieve which is vital for the program.

Does anyone know of a program, similar to XCode/Titanium etc where I can bundle a web based program together for distribution as a standalone desktop app for Windows and Apple. I'm happy to use SQLite as the database as I use this already in Xcode.

Comment: My 2 cents: it's not a great idea. PHP-driven desktop apps are kinda kludgy. The underlying concepts are totally different from a web app. I would consider learning a proper platform instead that specializes in desktop apps.

Comment: Yeah. Definitely not advisable. And where does the database reside?

Comment: And as for global variables, you shouldn't be using them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If all you use is a hammer...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)

PHP is in no way meant for building desktop applications.  It's meant to handle a request/response paradigm such as that of a web server.

You could in theory write a PHP commandline script and have a separate GUI application issue commandline instructions to the PHP script, but such a solution would be messy, klunky, and require your users to install PHP.

In the end, there's an entire slew of languages and development platforms vastly more suited to the task.  C and all its variants, Java, .NET (for Windoes applications)...

If you want to develop a desktop application, use a tool appropriate to developing desktop applications.  Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870/why-dont-people-use-php-for-desktop-applications).

Comment: Many thanks everyone. I would rather be told the honest truth than a second rate workaround. May I ask then what you would recommend for a cross platform language / program to use. C? Java? Adobe Air? Thanks again

Comment: Java is completely platform independent, as long as the machine has its version of JVM installed. But you can very well expect everyone to have that.

Comment: Thanks Arjun, I'll have to dust off my Java skills!

Comment: I don't know if you are still looking for a PHP solution to programming Desktop apps but you may want to checkout http://www.nightrain.naetech.com/ It's cross platform native packager for PHP.